# Comparing dates in js / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very beginner in JS / JQUERY.
I have this code:

```
var dateFromDB = '2019-12-27 19:12'; // this is data from MySQL
```

I need compare 2 date/datetime: dateFromDB with actualDataTime - 3 minutes

```
if (dateFromDB <= (actualDataTime - 3 minutes)]) {
     console.log('user is online');
} else{
console.log('user is offline offline')
}
```

How can I make it?

Comment: If you have the ability to store your timestamps with a timezone in your database you'll save yourself a lot of headache - especially if you have users that are in different timezones.

Comment: Try using https://momentjs.com, dates are hard in vanilla js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/).

After [installation](https://momentjs.com/docs/):

```
var dateFromDB = moment('2019-12-27 19:12').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm')
if (dateFromDB >= (moment().subtract(3, 'minutes')).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm')) {
     alert('user is online');
} else{
alert('user is offline')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just substract two Date objects and check the difference in milliseconds:

```
if (new Date(actualDataTime) - new Date(dateFromDB) <= 3 * 60 * 1000) {
   console.log('user is online');
} else{
   console.log('user is offline offline')
}
```

Comment: I try yours code: var online = null;
                                var actualDataTime = new Date(); 
                                if (new Date(actualDataTime) - new Date(chat[4]) <= 3 * 60 * 1000) {
                                    online = 'online'; 
                                } else{
                                    online = '';
                                } but it's not working

Comment: @traffka what date format do you use in `chat[4]` variable? That one you mentioned is working: 

if (new Date('2019-12-27 19:12') - new Date('2019-12-27 19:05') <= 3 * 60 * 1000) {
   console.log('user is online');
} else{
   console.log('user is offline offline')}